# Run JMX monitor collector listener using Jmeter Maven Plugin

Tags: jmeter, monitoring, jmx, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm using Jmeter maven plugin to execute jmx test files, it goes fine with GUI stress testing and web service testing :

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jmeter-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jmeter</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <overrideRootLogLevel>debug</overrideRootLogLevel>
                    <testFilesIncluded>
                        <jMeterTestFile>pim_stress.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                    </testFilesIncluded>
                    <resultsFileNameDateFormat>ddMMyyyy</resultsFileNameDateFormat>
                    <ignoreResultFailures>false</ignoreResultFailures>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <threadgroup.numberOfThreads>10</threadgroup.numberOfThreads>
                        <threadgroup.rampUp>1</threadgroup.rampUp>
                        <threadgroup.host>localhost</threadgroup.host>
                        <threadgroup.port>8332</threadgroup.port>
                    </propertiesUser>
                    <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then i needed to add a listener of type JMXMon Samples Collector listener in my Jmeter disktop application (Jmeter 2.9), this listener is used to plot JMX performance metrics over time when the test is running, the updated jmeter test works fine in Jmeter 2.9, here after the section of the listener :

```xml
        <kg.apc.jmeter.jmxmon.JMXMonCollector guiclass="kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.JMXMonGui" testclass="kg.apc.jmeter.jmxmon.JMXMonCollector" testname="jp@gc - JMXMon Samples Collector" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename">${__P(result.monitoring)}</stringProp>
          <longProp name="interval_grouping">1000</longProp>
          <boolProp name="graph_aggregated">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="include_sample_labels"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="exclude_sample_labels"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="start_offset"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="end_offset"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="include_checkbox_state">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="exclude_checkbox_state">false</boolProp>
          <collectionProp name="samplers">
            <collectionProp name="-362669779">
              <stringProp name="868201267">NbSessionsTotal</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="942166118">service:jmx:remoting-jmx://localhost:4697</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="105365">jmx</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="-1255434677">jmxadmin@1</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="377390660">pim.monitoring:service=JmxSystem</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="868201267">NbSessionsTotal</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="0"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="1237">false</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </kg.apc.jmeter.jmxmon.JMXMonCollector>
```

But when i tried to run this test plan (jmx file) by Jmeter maven plugin (for test automation reason), it return an error :

```
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: kg.apc.jmeter.jmxmon.JMXMonCollector : kg.apc.jmeter.jmxmon.JMXMonCollector
---- Debugging information ----
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.jmxmon.JMXMonCollector
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.jmxmon.JMXMonCollector
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/kg.apc.jmeter.jmxmon.JMXMonCollector
line number         : 430
-------------------------------
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:95)
... 19 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.jmxmon.JMXMonCollector
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService$XStreamWrapper$1.realClass(SaveService.java:94)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:70)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
... 35 more
```

Does anybody has an idea ?...thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you added JMeter plugin(s) to work with JMeter GUI instance, but omitted this step in jmeter-maven-plugin configuration. If you need to run JMeter test plan with non-standard plugins with maven, you need to configure jmeter-maven plugin as well:

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath#adding-jars-to-the-libext-directory

Comment: Thanks a lot automatictester; that was exactly what i need..it's very efficient ! :)