# Getting conflict error when running Jmeter Scripts using jmeter-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to achieve the Jmeter Maven integration. When I tried with jmeter-maven-plugin, I received the error messages as per mention in the below stackoverflow question:

[Run JMX monitor collector listener using Jmeter Maven Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134158/run-jmx-monitor-collector-listener-using-jmeter-maven-plugin)

I changed the my pom.xml as per suggested in the above blog and now not receiving that error (Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: kg.apc.jmeter.jmxmon.JMXMonCollector : kg.apc.jmeter.jmxmon.JMXMonCollector). However this doesn't resolved my execution problem and now I am facing below error.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 45.128 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-09T09:22:01+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 46M/958M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.10.1:jmeter (jmeter-tests) on project medewerkers-it: Execut
ion jmeter-tests of goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.10.1:jmeter failed: Plugin com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plug
in:1.10.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin
:jar:1.10.1 -> kg.apc:jmeter-plugins:jar:1.0.0 -> org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:0.90.1-cdh3u0 -> org.apache.thrift:thrift:jar:0.2.0: Faile
d to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.thrift:thrift:jar:0.2.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.thrift:thrift:pom:0.2.0 fr
om/to cdh.snapshot.repo (https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: https://repository.c
loudera.com/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/thrift/thrift/0.2.0/thrift-0.2.0.pom. Return code is: 409 , ReasonPhrase:Conflict
. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I tried to change the various version, however not able to resolve this. Below is pom.xml I am using. Could anyone please help on this front.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <skipITTests>true</skipITTests>
        <geb.version>0.10.0</geb.version>
        <selenium.version>2.48.2</selenium.version>
        <groovy.version>2.3.6</groovy.version>
        <spock.version>0.7-groovy-2.0</spock.version>
        <gson.version>2.3.1</gson.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.3.4</httpclient.version>
        <httpcore.version>4.3.2</httpcore.version>
        <surefire.plugin.version>2.12.4</surefire.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
            <artifactId>geb-spock</artifactId>
            <version>${geb.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipITTests}</skipTests>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*Spec.*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <geb.build.reportsDir>target/test-reports/geb</geb.build.reportsDir>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <providerSelection>1.8</providerSelection>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.8</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${spock.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>   

            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <reportDir>${project.build.directory}/jmeter-reports</reportDir>

                                <jmeterPlugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                        <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
                                    </plugin>

                                </jmeterPlugins>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>

             <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
               <phase>pre-site</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>transform</goal>
               </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
               <transformationSets>
                   <transformationSet>
                       <dir>${project.build.directory}/jmeter-reports</dir>
                       <stylesheet>src/test/resources/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl</stylesheet>
                       <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/site/jmeter-results</outputDir>
                       <fileMappers>
                           <fileMapper implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.FileExtensionMapper">
                               <targetExtension>html</targetExtension>
                           </fileMapper>
                       </fileMappers>
                   </transformationSet>
               </transformationSets>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>    
</project>
```

I purposefully mentioned other dependencies too, just to get the clear picture. Thanks in advance!

below is pom.xml which I have just changed and still facing the Errors as per I mentioned in the attachedment

```
[![<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <!-- IMPORTANT NOTE -->
    <!--
        This pom.xml does not contain a parent dependency to the webapplications pom.xml.
        Due to conflicting dependencies, the parent dependency was removed by Lieven Rigo and the Indian team, with consent of Andy Verberne.

        The child dependency in the webapplications pom.xml has also been removed.
        This means that maven-wise, the integration test set is a separate project.

    -->

    <groupId>net.atos.esuite.webapplications</groupId>
    <artifactId>medewerkers-it</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <!-- Project information -->
    <name>Atos e-Suite : Webapplications : Medewerkers IT testen</name>

    <properties>
        <skipITTests>true</skipITTests>
        <geb.version>0.10.0</geb.version>
        <selenium.version>2.48.2</selenium.version>
        <groovy.version>2.3.6</groovy.version>
        <spock.version>0.7-groovy-2.0</spock.version>
        <gson.version>2.3.1</gson.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.3.4</httpclient.version>
        <httpcore.version>4.3.2</httpcore.version>
        <surefire.plugin.version>2.12.4</surefire.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
            <artifactId>geb-spock</artifactId>
            <version>${geb.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Newly added dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipITTests}</skipTests>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*Spec.*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <geb.build.reportsDir>target/test-reports/geb</geb.build.reportsDir>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <providerSelection>1.8</providerSelection>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.8</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${spock.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Newly added plugins-->
            <!--            
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         -->
         <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <reportDir>${project.build.directory}/jmeter-reports</reportDir>

                                <jmeterPlugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                        <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
                                    </plugin>

                                </jmeterPlugins>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>


             <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
               <phase>pre-site</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>transform</goal>
               </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
               <transformationSets>
                   <transformationSet>
                       <dir>${project.build.directory}/jmeter-reports</dir>
                       <stylesheet>src/test/resources/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl</stylesheet>
                       <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/site/jmeter-results</outputDir>
                       <fileMappers>
                           <fileMapper implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.FileExtensionMapper">
                               <targetExtension>html</targetExtension>
                           </fileMapper>
                       </fileMappers>
                   </transformationSet>
               </transformationSets>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!--
     <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>codehausSnapshots</id>
            <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    -->


    <!--
    <repositories>
        <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
  </repository>
    </repositories>
    -->
    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

</project>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering from this transitive dependency issue:

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/142

You could try using the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT version of the plugin to see if that makes things better, the dependency resolution code has been rewritten and the new code may well handle it better (You can add alternate dependencies to try and fix the problems).

It's really an issue with the jmeter-plugins release in maven central.

If you do  decide to give it a go have a look at the [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) to see what the breaking changes are moving to 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT (The wiki hasn't been updated for 2.0.0 yet since it's not yet been released.

You will also need to use the sonatype snapshot repository in your POM file:

```
<!-- Use this to allow us to use a SNAPSHOT version of the jmeter-maven-plugin -->
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: After incorporating above changes, I am still facing the version conflict error. Could you please help on this. Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have done so i can have a look at it?

Comment: Hi Ardesco, I have pasted the modified pom.xml as per the suggestions by you and attached the snippet for the Error Log. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use version 2.6.0 of the [plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

It manages much better dependencies now and has smart defaults.

If you still need to exclude some artifact you can use :

```
 <excludedArtifacts>
      <exclusion>commons-pool2:commons-pool2</exclusion>
 </excludedArtifacts>
```